# Can't Install Kubernetes on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: kubernetes, ubuntu-16.04, kvm

I have tried to install Kubernetes on 3 separate Ubuntu 16.04 machines, with poor results. On all three machines, the recommended installation, using snap and conjure-up did not work:

```
gknight@pz1:~$ sudo snap install conjure-up --classic
[sudo] password for gknight: 
gknight@pz1:~$ sudo reboot
gknight@pz1:~$ conjure-up kubernetes
dropping privs did not work
```

This is the snap version:

```
gknight@pz1:~$ snap --version
snap    2.33.1ubuntu2
snapd   2.33.1ubuntu2
series  16
ubuntu  16.04
kernel  4.4.0-130-generic
```

On two, local, machines, the repository method worked:

```
sudo curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add 
add the following to sources.list.d, as kubernetes.list:
deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main
apt-get update
apt-get install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl kubernetes-cni
```

But, on a remote 512mb KVM VPS (PnZ Hosting), although Docker installs and runs just fine, when I install kubelet, etc. and do *nothing* else, it soon runs the uptime load average up to 12 or so, and I can barely get through to it to reboot. There are no obvious error messages (and swap is turned off).

So, does the "conjure-up" method work on *any* Ubuntu 16.04 today?

What is Kubernetes *doing* that's taking over the KVM machine?

Finally, is there any other way to install Kubernetes?

Answer (score 2):

> remote 512mb KVM VPS

That's almost certainly the problem, as I don't know of very much software nowadays that will run in that little memory. It matches your experience that the machine will start swapping like mad, driving the I/O pressure through the roof

Comment: Indeed, that's way too small. Even minikube creates a 2GB RAM virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @Matthew & @Michael - 512mb is not enough to run Kubernetes. 
Increase your memory up to 1GB min and retry.

> Apiserver and etcd together are fine on a machine with 1 core and 1GB
>   RAM for clusters with 10s of nodes.

You can read more documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/scratch/).
Conjure method works fine for me using [this instruction](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/ubuntu/local/).

```
Ubuntu version: 
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:        16.04
```

Ways to install Kubernetes:

- [Local Kubernetes development with LXD](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/ubuntu/local/)
- [Running Kubernetes Locally via Minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/minikube/)
- [Using kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/)
- Use prepared cloud solutions, for example [Google Kubernetes Engine](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/), [Amazon EKS](https://aws.amazon.com/eks/) or many many others.

Comment: Amazon EKS service provides an ability to spin up and test Kubernetes in 15 minutes for just a fraction of dollar. Maybe that can help you to play with Kubernetes on the real cloud environment and decide if it is worth it for your concrete case. If running the system on AWS is OK for you then EKS would be probably the best choice. Here is an article that I wrote recently when reviewing Amazon EKS, maybe it can help you to quickly gather the information required: https://bekitzur.com/blog/amazon-eks/

Comment: Amazon also recommends the minimal cloud instance type that can be used as Kubernetes worker. Currently for latest docker and Kubernetes 1.10 it's t2.small with 2gb RAM.